# jquery update div with new content

Tags: jquery, click

I want to click on a div and update another divs content.  Easy enough to do in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xt584/)
but it is not working in my actual project.  When I move the code to my project, the click is never registered and the console.log() never fires.  Any ideas on using Chrome Developer Tools or Firebug to troubleshoot this. When there are no obvious clues, like syntax errors etc. what are the more elusive clues to look for?

I added this:

```
    $('.routers').click(function(event){ 
             $('#titleBarContainerRightier').append('Scooby Doo!');
        console.log("click!");
```

To this and the click events stopped showing up:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        loadDATA('JSON/data.json', "DSC123");

        $('.routers').click(function(event){ 
                 $('#titleBarContainerRightier').append('Scooby Doo!');
            console.log("click!");

         });
       });
```

Comment: Is the .routers element dynamic ?

Comment: is `.routers` load via `loadDATA()`?

Comment: What is in the `loadDATA` function? Are there any errors in the console? Is `.routers` appended to your page dynamically?

Comment: From syntax highlighting it looks like event is a reserved word. Maybe you should not use it as a parameter name? **Edit:** Ok, I checked. It's not.

Comment: I find that the best way to debug things like this is to copy your .click function and paste it under chrome console and hit enter. If it works then you need to use .on (.live, etc) instead of .click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem your having is coming from whatever your loadData function is without knowing that i cannot assist much but heres my proof it works without it.

http://jsfiddle.net/th3fallen/YV8fN/

Comment: Yeup, I tried putting the code in the loadData function but no luck there either.  I think you are right.  The buttons are created dynamically from the data, so maybe the click event is confused when it first arrives on the scene.

Comment: If the button is created from the load data the problem is the .click function try using .live('click', function() {} instead